# utilising a time function so that every minute a function is triggered that will subtract a certain amount from an integer

Tags: java

I am trying to write a function that will utilize my time class so that for every minute that passes 25 is subtracted from an integer. At the moment I am attempting to use an `if` statement so that every time a multiple of 2 is passed, a function is triggered to subtract from a variable, so for every 2 minutes an amount is subtracted from the variable (through a triggered function).

I believe there is a more efficient way to do this through a loop but I'm unsure how to do this.

Timer class

```java
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class Timer {

    public long PerfectTimer() throws InterruptedException {
        boolean x = true;
        long displayMinutes = 0;
        long starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while(x) {
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            long timepassed = System.currentTimeMillis() - starttime;
            long secondspassed = timepassed / 1000;
            if(secondspassed == 60) {
                secondspassed = 0;
                starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
            if((secondspassed % 60) == 0) {
                displayMinutes++;
            }
//            System.out.println(displayMinutes+"::"+secondspassed);
        }
        return displayMinutes;
    }
}

//subtract function
public void changingStatsOverTime() throws InterruptedException {
    if(t.PerfectTimer() % 2 == 0) {
        s.addTiredness();
        s.addHunger();
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest you look at the java.util.Timer class and the associated TimerTask class.  You're doing a lot of work that just doesn't need to be done.

Comment: As @Ryan suggest here is a link to some examples https://www.baeldung.com/java-timer-and-timertask